# Segmentation fault in base number program?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I keep trying to test this code but I keep getting a segmentation fault in my `power()` function. The code is supposed to take a word made up of lowercase letters and change the word to a number of `base 10`. The word is supposed to take on the form of a number of `base 20`, where `'a' = 0, 'b' = 1,...., 't' = 19;`

```
int power(int i){
if(i==1){
    return 20;
}else{
    return 20*power(i--);
 }
}

int main(){
int len;
char mayan[6];
int n;
int val;
while(scanf("%s", mayan)){
    val = 0;
    n = 0;
    for(len = 0; mayan[len] != '\0'; len++){
        mayan[len] = tolower(mayan[len]);
        mayan[len] = mayan[len] - 'a';
    }
    for(i = 0; len >= 0; len--, i++){
        if(mayan[len] <= 19){
            n = n + mayan[len] * power(i);
        }else{
            fprintf(stderr, "Error, not a base 20 input \n");
            val = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(val==0){
        printf("%d \n", n);
    }
}
return val;
```

}

Comment: `20*power(i--)` It does not stop the function call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were three mistakes in your code.

- Case for `i==0` not added in the `power` function, which basically translates to any number to the power of zero is one i.e. **x^0 = 1;**.
- Instead of using `return 20*power(i--);` for your recursive call, use `return 20*power(i-1);`. `i--` is **post decrement operator**, which means that, it will return the value of `i` as it is and will the decrement it for further use, which is not what you want. Also, you altogether don't even want to change the value of `i` for this iteration too; what you want to do is use a value one less than `i` for the next iteration, which is what, passing `i-1`, will do.
- Add a `len--` in the initialization of the `for(i = 0; len >= 0; len--, i++)` loop, because `len` is now over the last index of the input because of the previous loop.

Correcting these mistakes the final code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int power(int i)
{
 if(i==0)
 {
  return 1;
 }

 if(i==1)
 {
    return 20;
 }
 else
 {
    return 20*power(i-1);
 }
}
int main()
{
  int len,i;
  char mayan[6];
  int n;
  int val;
  while(scanf("%s", mayan))
  {
    val = 0;
    n = 0;
    for(len = 0; mayan[len] != '\0'; len++)
    {
        mayan[len] = tolower(mayan[len]);
        mayan[len] = mayan[len] - 'a';
    }

    for(i = 0, len--; len >= 0; len--, i++)
    {
        if(mayan[len] <= 19)
        {
            n = n + mayan[len] * power(i);
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error, not a base 20 input \n");
            val = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(val==0)
    {
        printf("%d \n", n);
    }
 }
 return val;
}
```

Note that, your code would essentially only work for at most a five digit base `20` number, because, the array `mayan` that you are using to store it has size `6`, of which, one character will be spent for storing the terminating character `\0`. I recommend that you increase the size of the array `mayan` unless you want to support only five digit base `20` numbers.

Comment: _"Just three mistakes in your code"_. Well, three mistakes aren't less, they are a lot. In a massive program debugging three mistakes, would take days. Also, you should never say to a beginner that if you do three mistakes, it is okay. You are not saying it directly, but indirectly. Then the programmers writing style will be bad, and when he will do massive programs, there will be huge problems caused.

Comment: @AshishAhuja Oh! right sir... I was just trying to be encouraging and optimistic ;)

Comment: Yes, being encouraging is good, but this will lead to a fault in the programmers style of writing code. Thus, next time just say: _"There are three mistakes in your code"_, which will not discourage the programmer, but will not even harm the style of the programmer. Sometimes, saying there is just one mistake is okay, but three mistakes ain't.

Comment: The "corrected code" will overflow the size of `int`

Comment: Yeah right! Thanks for the incite, I will edit that.

Comment: @M.M I just wanted to focus on the main problem rather than changing the data types that the OP posted. Do you suggested I change those as well?